# Close Telerik radgridview custom Filter Control

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik, radgridview

i am using telerik silverlight lib. Version = 2011.1.411.1040

i am create one custom filter control for telerik silverlight  RadGridView, 
in this control one close button at right hand top corner

i want to close filter control on click of close button, how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after spend very long time for resolve this issue. i hope bellow code can help you, it was help me so

```
private void btnclose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   FilteringDropDown down = Telerik.Windows.Controls.UIElementExtensions.ParentOfType<FilteringDropDown>(this);
   if (down != null)
   {
       down.IsDropDownOpen = false;
   }
}
```